# Back Button Navigation Controller works in Simulator but not Phone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

OK, this is weird. When I use a Navigation Controller, back button appears on Simulator, but doesn't on the iPhone.

Any ideas?

Comment: reset the simulator and remove build in a project.

Comment: If you run too many methods on viewDidLoad in an old phone, it won't fully load Navigation Bar and thus the Back button. This was a large method on a 3GS without Wifi. Back never loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with phone processor power, see below comment and answer:

If you run too many methods on viewDidLoad in an old phone, it won't fully load Navigation Bar and thus the Back button. This was a large method on a 3GS without Wifi. Back never loaded.

Comment: I re-wrote for ARC and had no issues.